# Count the n-grams that match a pattern using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

If I use:

```
import re
words = re.findall(r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b", "aaa, bbb ccc. ddd\naaa xxx yyy")
print(words)
print(len(words))
```

as expected, I get:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'xxx', 'yyy']
7
```

Now I would like to modify the regular expression in order to also be able to count 2-grams and 3-grams, taking into account punctuation and newlines. In particular, the result I expect in this case is:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'bbb ccc', 'aaa xxx', 'xxx yyy', 'aaa xxx yyy']
11
```

How can I modify the regular expression to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer**

```
import re
from itertools import chain

s = "aaa, bbb ccc. ddd\naaa xxx yyy"
result = list(chain(*(re.findall('(?=((?<!\w)\w\w\w+' + ' \w\w\w+' * n + '(?!\w)))', s)
                      for n in range(3))))
```

Output:

```
>>> result
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'bbb ccc', 'aaa xxx', 'xxx yyy', 'aaa xxx yyy']
```

**Improved answer** (thanks to @CasimiretHippolyte for the useful comments)

```
import re
from itertools import chain

s = "aaa, bbb ccc. ddd\naaa xxx yyy"
result = list(chain(*(re.findall(r'\b(?=(\w\w\w+' + ' \w\w\w+' * n + '))', s)
                      for n in range(3))))
```

Comment: Note that since the last quantifier is greedy, you don't need to check if a word character left at the end with `(?!\w)`. Also, instead of `(?<!\w)`, you can start the pattern with a word-boundary `\b(?=(...` (you can put it outside of the lookahead, it's only an assertion and doesn't consume characters, also it discards immediately most of useless positions in the string without entering the lookahead).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks a lot for your comment! I'm not sure about `\b` part. I can't get it working. Currently I have `\b(?=(\w\w\w+....`, but the returned result is empty

Comment: That's strange, it isn't supposed to change the final result: see https://regex101.com/r/31Sbcd/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It is weird indeed. Check my tests here: https://tio.run/##rY/BDoIwEETv/YqRC1sgJOpV449wKVC0SW3Jtgb4egRDTEyMJ2dPMzubl@2nePPuOM/m3nuOYC069neYqDl6bwO2RXNTxgkRcEailCpQ1zWapinRtm3llgjjOGKapkSwDg8b90vVmhDpdUoZsS4741plLaVVTZczVcM6eYocKd4mg1sDKdMCQQp8V@d56RkHVu6q6SgXbeTDL/LKpctpVw3y73jRs3GRtv/lhz3IeX4C

Comment: You need a raw string: `r'\b(?=(....` otherwise `\b` is seen in the string as a backspace character.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks a lot again for your help, let me edit the answer and give you credits

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Just a curiosity: testing the result I realized that the answer does not handle compound words (with a hyphen). For example "e-waste management" should be two words. If I put in your answer `s = 'e-waste management'` I get `['waste', 'management', 'waste management']` while I should get `['e-waste', 'management', 'e-waste management']`. I tried 

`list(chain(*(re.findall(r'\b(?=(\w\w\w+' + '[- ]*\w\w\w+' * n + '))', s) for n in range(3))))`

but it doesn't work.